# Download, get the filename and execute the file

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am posting here to ask you for help, thank you first of all for reading my message and being able to help me. :)

So here's the problem, I have a little program that I'm creating, in this one, I integrated a button that normally allows to download a tool to run it.

However the link of the file does not point directly in .exe it is a link like this one : 
mydomain.com/file/file48.php

The problem is that I manage to get the file, but this one is named file48.php and gets the extension of a php file, what I would like is to get the original name of the downloaded .exe file in order to be able to execute it within my application.

Here is the current code I'm using :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim client As New WebClient

    AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadFileCompleted

    client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https ://mydomain.com/files/index.php"), fileName, filename)
End Sub

Private Sub client_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim client = DirectCast(sender, WebClient)

    client.Dispose()

    Dim filename As String = CType(e.UserState, String)
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for your help, I've been searching for hours without much success...

Comment: So you just want to change the extension in the DownloadFileCompleted handler then execute the file?

Comment: Hello, I would like the name of the downloaded file to remain exactly the same and then I would like to be able to run it automatically at the end of the download.

Comment: So will System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "exe") work?  Then it's just a case of executing the exe using process.start(...)

Comment: BC30451 'fileName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its level of protection. I'm starting to lose my mind. :/

Comment: In the DownloadFileComplete hander Dim filename As String = CType(e.UserState, String), then System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "exe")

Comment: I have the same problem with my code :/